# Python KivyMD icon is not displayed on Andriod app

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Please help, I am updating my android app. It was written with KivyMD. I used icon this time. The icon is displayed in debugging on Pycharm without problem, but not on my phone. I can still click on it, but I just can't see the icon.

Kivy

```
<WordScreen>
    name: 'wordscreen'
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "VOCGO"
        elevation: 5
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        height: '40dp'
        right_action_items: [["home-outline", lambda x: app.set_screen()]]
```

Spec

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json,ttf,txt

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivyMD,pillow,requests

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 29
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. Thanks for the advice. It is to do with the bug mentioned about. I have to specify sdl2_ttf==2.0.15. The trick is you have to clean the buildozer build. After updating the spec, run

```
buildozer android clean
```

then:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

My requirement is this in the end.

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc3,kivymd==0.104.1,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,requests
```

I also tried this requirement, worked as well.

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,requests
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the kivymd branches has that bug, the version I use to make sure icons will be there is, in your buildozer.spec requirements use:

requirements = kivymd==0.104.1,kivy==2.0.0,...

In case your app uses classes that only the latest kivymd version has, then you can download the latest module and combine it all together with the kivymd version 0.104.1 specified in the requirements

Comment: requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1,pillow,requests. 
Updated. Unfortunately, icons are still no show, clicking and other app functions are working fine still.

Comment: requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc3,kivymd==0.104.1,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pillow,requests.

I also researched about the bug, it was saying the sdl2_ttf version. I did that. But it didn't work. 

This is the link I found.
https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/257

Comment: Did you delete the ".buildozer" folder before changing and running again the command to package the app? Remember that buildozer does not replace modules already downloaded, so even if you change the requirements but if you don't delete that folder, your app still have the old one

Comment: Yes, that is right. In the end, I didn't delete the buildozer folder. I ran buildozer android clean. After that the packages were unpacked one by one again. That gave the app the new life. Thank you very much!